# insert or replace in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to insert of replace if exist in database with codeigniter
this my model

```
public function upload($id_akun,$data){
               $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM akun WHERE
id_akun = '{$data['id_akun']}' ");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);

if (empty($count)) {

     $this->db->insert('foto', $data);  
}
elseif ($count == 1) {
   $this->db->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun']);
                    $this->db->update('foto', $data);  
}
```

I'm succesful replace(update) data if exist but it not inserting data if (empty($count))

conditional ($count == 1)---> it's ok
condtional (empty($count))--->problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**In Model**

```
public function upload($id_akun,$table){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM akun WHERE id_akun = '$id_akun' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count)){
        $this->db->insert('foto', $table);
        return 0; 
    }
    elseif ($count == 1) {
        $this->db->where('id_akun', $id_akun);
        $this->db->update('foto', $table);  
        return 1;
    }
    elseif (($count >= 1) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$id_akun = 25;
$table = 'table_name';

$result = $this->model_name->upload($id_akun,$table);

switch ($result) {
    case 0:
        $output = 'Data Inserted'
        break;
    case 1:
        $output = 'Record Inserted'
        break;
    case 2:
        $output = 'Multiple Record Found'
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this ..

```
public function upload($id_akun,$data){       
   $this->db->where('id_akun',$data['id_akun']);
   $this->db->from('akun');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $rowcount = $query->num_rows();

  if ($rowcount==0) {

    $this->db->insert('foto', $data);  
  }
 else {
   $this->db->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun']);
                $this->db->update('foto', $data);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're checking to see if the result of a `count()` is empty. That will always evaluate to false.

```
public function upload($id_akun, $data)
{
    //use active record methods, otherwise, you need to sanitize input
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun']);
    $query = $this->db->get('akun'); 

    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
        $this->db->update...
    }else{
         ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

The function **result_array()** results **empty array** if nothing is find in fetching record. Hence when you fetch record it returns you the empty array and you are taking count of this empty array which returns you the zero length which is not equals to empty hence your condition is always remain false.

You may use the following Code.

**Code**

```
     function upload($id_akun, $data) {
       //use active record methods, otherwise, you need to sanitize input
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun']);
       $query = $this->db->get('akun');
       if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {

           //write your Insert query here

       } elseif ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

          //write your Update query here 

       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several benefits to using Active Record (or Query Builder as its going to be called soon):

1. Security
2. Code-Cleanliness
3. Database-Agnostic

so, all time try to use active record.

```
<?php
public function upload($id_akun,$data){ 
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun'])->from('akun')->get();
    $count = $query->num_rows();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if ($count == 0)
        return $this->db->insert('foto', $data);
    }
    elseif ($count > 1) {
        $this->db->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun']);
        return $this->db->update('foto', $data);  
    }
}
```